# Escape character cosmos db query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a very simple query which i want to execute. But the data which is stored in cosmos db document has single quote. So when I run the query it is giving me error. Below is my query

```
SELECT c.id,c.path, c.docName FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.path, '/Sandbox/Shared Documents/New Document/Women's Health')
```

I have already tried multiple single quotes for e.g. '' I have tried \ I have tried double quotes as well

Comment: You can try to escape character with ' with  \' ?
Or you can also try to write the path in the double quote "/Sandbox/Shared Documents/New Document/Women's Health" instead of single quote

Comment: I have tried multiple single quotes, \ double quotes. Its not working

Comment: You could use Replace to parse it .. but might required a concat statement using a stored procedure, but if you can change your ' into an `, that would be the trick.  OR is there a way to rename the source directory and just do it manually and why you are at it, why not convert the spaces into _  underscore?

Comment: This seems like a portal challenge and not a programmatic challenge, correct? Does this work via a code-based solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your document has the key-value pair below:

```
"path": "/Sandbox/Shared Documents/New Document/Women's Health"
```

The WHERE clause below should work for you:

```
STARTSWITH(c.path, "/Sandbox/Shared Documents/New Document/Women's Health")
```

Notice that the WHERE clause above has the whole path wrapped with double quotes. Let me know if your key-value pair is different.